# Benchmarking matrix multiplication performance: C++ (eigen) is much slower than Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, benchmarking, eigen

I am trying to estimate how good is Python performance comparing to C++.

Here is my Python code:

```
a=np.random.rand(1000,1000) #type is automaically float64
b=np.random.rand(1000,1000) 
c=np.empty((1000,1000),dtype='float64')

%timeit a.dot(b,out=c)

#15.5 ms ± 560 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And here is my C++ code that I compile with Xcode in release regime:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Dense>
#include <time.h>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //RNG generator
    unsigned int seed = clock();
    srand(seed);

    int Msize=1000, Nloops=10;

    MatrixXd m1=MatrixXd::Random(Msize,Msize);
    MatrixXd m2=MatrixXd::Random(Msize,Msize);
    MatrixXd m3=MatrixXd::Random(Msize,Msize);

    cout << "Starting matrix multiplication test with " << Msize << 
    "matrices" << endl;
    clock_t start=clock();
    for (int i=0; i<Nloops; i++)
        m3=m1*m2;
    start = clock() - start;

    cout << "time elapsed for 1 multiplication: " << start / ((double) 
CLOCKS_PER_SEC * (double) Nloops) << " seconds" <<endl;
return 0;
```

}

And the result is:

```
Starting matrix multiplication test with 1000matrices
time elapsed for 1 multiplication: 0.148856 seconds
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Which means that C++ program is 10 times slower.

Alternatively, I've tried to compile cpp code in MAC terminal:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.5/include/eigen3/eigen main.cpp -o my_exec -O3

./my_exec

Starting matrix multiplication test with 1000matrices
time elapsed for 1 multiplication: 0.150432 seconds
```

I am aware of very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100079/c-eigen-sparse-matrix-multiplication-much-slower-than-python-scipy-sparse), however, it looks like there the issue was in matrix definitions. In my example I've used default eigen functions to create matrices from uniform distribution.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Edit: I found out, that while numpy uses multithreading, Eigen does not use multiple threads by default (checked by `Eigen::nbThreads()` function).
As suggested, I used `-march=native` option which reduced computation time by a factor of 3. Taking into account 8 threads available on my MAC, I can believe that with multithreading numpy runs 3 times faster.

Comment: It is highly unlikely Python will have better performance than C++.

Comment: Mikhail, did you check whether `numpy` possibly uses multithreading or GPU offloading? I doubt `Eigen` does it by default, but in Python it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @RushabhMehta it is said in eigen documentation that the performance is very close to optimal, e.g. BLAS

Comment: @MaxLanghof thanks for the useful comment. As far as I understand, Eigen should also do multithreading. Even if doesn't, the performance shouldn't be 10x times worse, since I only ahve 4 cores and 8 threads. Going to check on GPU

Comment: For more information about the underlying library used by numpy, show the output of `np.show_config()`.

Comment: I don't think it would matter but in the C++ code you randomize `m3`.  What happens if you don't and leave it empty like you do in python?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for the suggestion. I can see that I definetly use mkl (installed it a while ago) for numpy. Didn't see any trace of GPU. In addition, on My Mac I only have Radeon GPU, while the nvidia one is required

Comment: @NathanOliver I've just checked - the test time is essentially the same (as expected)

Comment: @MikhailGenkin OK.  I figured as much but wanted to make sure.

Comment: I don't think pthon `dot` does what you think it does and that is why it is faster.

Comment: @MarekR numpy.dot multiplies matrix by matrix. I am 100% sure, as I have some python experience

Comment: See my answer I run simple example and it doesn't multiply matrix, but multiplication operator does.

Comment: @MarekR `.dot` does matrix by matrix multiplication. `x*y` does term-by-term multiplication, which I didn't consider in my test. Amyway, term by term multiplication is way faster. In python `c=a*b` is executed in 2.5 ms (compare to original 15 ms in my quesiton)

Comment: @MikhailGenkin, do the results change much if you increase `Nloops` in the C++ code (to, say, 100)?

Comment: `-march=native`

Comment: clock is not the right function to measure performance.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser no, not really

Comment: @MarcGlisse, wow adding this option reduced computation time by a factor of 3 (now it is only 45-50 ms per loop). Taking into account, that multithreading was not used (there is a function in eigen that allows me to check it), I believe that unveils the mystery

Comment: @n.m. , why not? I can use high-precision timer from c++11, but there is no need, as running times are all of the order of seconds

Comment: Compiling with `-fopenmp` would enable multithreading, except that you are on Mac so you probably have a fake g++ and possibly no openmp.

Comment: @MarcGlisse that is completely accurate. I am trying to set it up

Comment: clock measures cpu time. any multithreading or sleep will throw it off.

Comment: On mac you can easily install any version of g++/clang with OpenMP support through macport, or you can also ask Eigen to fallback to Apples's accelerate: `-framework Accelerate -DEIGEN_USE_BLAS`.

Comment: I'm observing eigen being more than ten times *faster* than numpy, with `-Ofast -march=native` flags. (55 vs 700 ms per iteration)

Comment: For Eigen, write `m3.noalias()=m1*m2;` to avoid a matrix copy.

Comment: @n.m. This entirely depends on your BLAS implementation. Essentially, this benchmark compares Eigen's matrix multiplication with the BLAS used by numpy.

Comment: @chtz I don't have any special BLAS. All I have is `apt-get install python-numpy`, like 99% of us.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions: with `-framework Accelerate -DEIGEN_USE_BLAS` time increases by a factor of two, so it does not help. with `-Ofast -march=native` time is the same as before (`O3 -march=native`). With `m3.noalias()=m1*m2` time decreases a little bit (by like 4%)

Comment: @MikhailGenkin Did you see the comment by n.m.? The way you measure time doesn't do what you want for multithreading.

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes, I have. The bigger problem is that I never used multithreading so far. I am currently struggling with OpenMP installation

Comment: Maybe Numpy is using the GPGPU (e.g. thru OpenCL or CUDA)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch CUDA is not possible with non-nVidia GPU.  I never configured/installed OpenCL. np.show_config() never showed any trace of GPU

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After long and painful installations and compilations I've performed benchmarks in Matlab, C++ and Python.

My computer: MAC OS High Sierra 10.13.6 with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7920HQ CPU @ 3.10GHz (4 cores, 8 threads). I have Radeon Pro 560 4096 MB so that there was no GPUs involved in these tests (and I never configured openCL and didn't see it in `np.show_config()`).

Software:
Matlab 2018a, Python 3.6, C++ compilers: Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2), g++-8 (Homebrew GCC 8.2.0) 8.2.0

1) Matlab performance: time= (14.3 +- 0.7 ) ms with 10 runs performed

```
a=rand(1000,1000);
b=rand(1000,1000);
c=rand(1000,1000);
tic
for i=1:100
    c=a*b;
end
toc/100
```

2) Python performance (`%timeit a.dot(b,out=c)`): 15.5 +- 0.8

I've also installed mkl libraries for python. With numpy linked against mkl: 14.4+-0.7 - it helps, but very little.

3) C++ performance. The following changes to the original (see the question) code were applied:

- `noalias` function to avoid unnecessary temporal matrices creation.
- Time was measured with c++11 `chorno` library

Here I used a bunch of different options and two different compilers:

```
3.1 clang++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.5/include/eigen3/eigen main.cpp -O3
```

Execution time ~ 146 ms

```
3.2 Added -march=native option:
```

Execution time ~ 46 +-2 ms

```
3.3 Changed compiler to GNU g++ (in my mac it is called gpp by custom-defined alias):

gpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.5/include/eigen3/eigen main.cpp -O3
```

Execution time 222 ms

```
3.4 Added - march=native option:
```

Execution time ~ 45.5 +- 1 ms

At this point I realized that Eigen does not use multiple threads. I installed openmp and added -fopenmp flag. Note that on the latest clang version openmp does not work, thus I had to use g++ from now on. I also made sure I am actually using all available threads by monitoring the value of `Eigen::nbthreads()` and by using MAC OS activity monitor.

```
3.5  gpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.5/include/eigen3/eigen main.cpp -O3 -march=native -fopenmp
```

Execution time: 16.5 +- 0.7 ms

3.6 Finally, I installed Intel mkl libraries. In the code it is quite easy to use them: I've just added `#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL` macro and that's it. It was hard to link all the libraries though:

```
gpp -std=c++11 -DMKL_LP64 -m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.5/include/eigen3/eigen -L${MKLROOT}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${MKLROOT}/lib -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl   main.cpp -o my_exec_intel -O3 -fopenmp  -march=native
```

Execution time: 14.33 +-0.26 ms.  (Editor's note: this answer originally claimed to have used `-DMKL_ILP64` which is [not supported](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html).  Maybe it used to be, or happened to work.)

Conclusion:

- Matrix-matrix multiplication in Python/Matlab is highly optimized. It is not possible (or, at least, very hard) to do significantly better (on a CPU).
- CPP code (at least on MAC platform) can only achieve similar performance if fully optimized, which includes full set of optimization options and Intel mkl libraries.
  I could have installed old clang compiler with openmp support, but since the single-thread performance is similar (~46 ms), it looks like this will not help.
- It would be great to try it with native Intel compiler `icc`. Unfortunately, this is proprietary software, unlike Intel mkl libraries.

Thanks for useful discussion,

Mikhail

Edit: For comparison, I've also benchmarked my GTX 980 GPU using cublasDgemm function. Computational time = 12.6 ms, which is compatible with other [results.](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/Misc/mygpu.pdf) The reason CUDA is almost as good as CPU is the following: my GPU is poorly optimized for doubles. With floats, GPU time =0.43 ms, while Matlab's is 7.2 ms

Edit 2: to gain significant GPU acceleration, I would need to benchmark matrices with much bigger sizes, e.g. 10k x 10k

Edit 3: changed the interface from MKL_ILP64 to MKL_LP64 since ILP64 is [not supported.](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html)

Comment: What version of GCC, of Clang? What processor?

Comment: Thanks, added in the begging of the answer